# Why can't I find Kartana in Pokemon Sun?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I'm currently completing the post Elite Four content where you find all of the Ultra Beasts.

I've already found and caught the first three, but I'm having trouble finding the fourth one, Kartana. I have been searching all over Route 17 for over an hour, but it has not appeared.

I know I have already talked to Looker for sure because I remember that Looker's partner felt pain after the appearance of this Ultra Beast. Nanu then gave us advice on where to find it.

So why am I having issues finding it? Any suggestions?

Comment: I pretty much want to answer that you are really unlucky and you should keep trying. But I am not sure it would be considered an answer. :D

Comment: @Isuka I thought the same thing, but I guess I didn't want to believe it XD I'll keep trying, but I'll leave my question up until I do

Comment: [This site](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/186508/20161121/pok%C3%A9mon-sun-and-moon-guide-how-to-get-all-the-legendaries-and-ultra-beasts.htm) says that you can find Kartana at Haina Desert and Malie Garden

Comment: @PythonMaster But this [site](http://www.thegamersdrop.com/2016/11/24/pokemon-sun-moon-guide-ultra-beasts-find-14762/) says differently...Either way, I looked at Malie Garden too. No luck :(

Comment: [Serebii](http://serebii.net/sunmoon/ultrabeasts.shtml) is a very reliable source, and it says Route 17 and Malie Garden. It also says in the section about Nihilego that the music changes when it's there, so you might want to turn up the volume and listen for unusual music.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've talked to Looker and Anabel on Route 8 after catching Xurkitree, but it seems like you forgot to go to the Route 13 motel before attempting to find the next Ultra Beast.

After going to the Route 13 motel and talking to Nanu, he should give you a hint as to where to find the next Ultra Beast, and you're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you while I was using max repels.
However, the second I stopped re-applying max repels, I found the last Kartana!  It might work, might not, worth a try.

Comment: I'm not using any repels, but thanks